# Typo3 translation of dialect languages using typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

i am working on multi language site using typo3 6.2. where i am using typoscript in template to receive the language translation

the code to receive the language translation using typoscript is

```
temp.applyonline = TEXT
temp.applyonline {
data = LLL:EXT:ext_name/pi1/locallang.xml:direct_request
stdWrap.wrap = <div class="ceWrap"><br />|</div>
}
```

This code is working fine for normal languages but not for language dialect such as austrian german.

The dialect translation are working otherwise but the issues happens only when translation of dialect is trying to get via typoscript

Please help

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is no text displayed? Is it a problem with the umlauts?

Comment: Can you provide more information on exactly what it is that it not working?